# Where TortoiseGit saves dialog positions and sizes

Tags: tortoisegit

I love to use TortoiseGit as a GUI for several git commands, especially since I have a script to fire Tortoise dialogs from the console.

Sometimes I like to use Log dialog just to visualize the commits graph and in those times commit message and commit changes boxes are just in the way, however, changing their sizes back and forth every time is a bothersome thing to do.

Thus, I've been thinking about adding some option to my script which would modify Log dialog layout before opening it, however, I cannot find any options or files where this can be edited.

Unfortunately, googling it, searching through manual, browsing gitlab issues and stackoverflow questions did not bring any results. :(

Can someone help me with this? Or point a direction where I should look in? Even information that this is not possible would be tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information about Dialog sizes are stored in registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit\TortoiseProc\ResizableState`.

You can find more information about the format here: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/blob/3763e73fa54b0763ca9f5e8646ecb46cf0b8e879/ext/ResizableLib/ResizableWndState.cpp

It can be modified like this:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit\TortoiseProc\ResizableState /v LogDlgSizer1 /t REG_DWORD /d 800 /f > NUL
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit\TortoiseProc\ResizableState /v LogDlgSizer2 /t REG_DWORD /d 840 /f > NUL
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!